# Using UNION doesn't give the right result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. In my table `Wallets` I have 5 Coins: LTC, BTC, ETH, BNB and USDT. Now I first want to select the coin with the highest value, but not USDT. And the second coin must be the USDT coin. So I tried this Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Wallets
WHERE NOT Coin='USDT' 
ORDER BY Value DESC LIMIT 1 
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM Wallets
WHERE Coin='USDT'
```

But that gives me all the coins except USDT... The weird thing is that when I run the 2 queries seperate from each other, the results are correct. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an example of my table layout:

```
+------+----------+-------+
| Coin | Quantity | Value |
+------+----------+-------+
| LTC  |       10 |   200 |
| BTC  |        2 | 12000 |
| BNB  |        0 |     2 |
| ETH  |        0 |   0.1 |
| USDT |        0 |     0 |
+------+----------+-------+
```

Now I want this result:

```
+------+----------+-------+
| Coin | Quantity | Value |
+------+----------+-------+
| BTC  |        2 | 12000 |
| USDT |        0 |     0 |
+------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicated records, which is most likely the case most likely you need to use `UNION ALL`  instead.

Comment: Still same result then!

Comment: *"Still same result then!"* i didn't look at the total query mine other comment was just a guess.. In that case see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks for improving my question, because its my first sql question!

Comment: Use parentheses, Luke!

Comment: indeed @PaulSpiegel i think it's time for bed.. also topicstarter your SQL code should error on MySQL without parentheses you sure your are using MySQL?

Comment: Yes I am sure, no errors !?

Comment: "Yes I am sure, no errors !?" [wierd](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igLC7c8SQdvTLhXWeGKDsN/0) as i tryed MySQL versions 5.5 to 8.0 all give a error.

Comment: [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igLC7c8SQdvTLhXWeGKDsN/1) is the version how it should be on MySQL, mdem7 's answer is [wrong](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igLC7c8SQdvTLhXWeGKDsN/1), both statements need to use parentheses like @PaulSpiegel already suggested.  p.s most likely you don't have to use `UNION ALL`

Comment: @RaymondNijland you forgot to "fork" your fix.

Comment: *"you forgot to "fork" your fix"* thanks it's [forked](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igLC7c8SQdvTLhXWeGKDsN/2) (saved/updated) now @PaulSpiegel , time for bed it seams.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk `UNION` is a shortcut for `UNION DISTINCT` and will try to remove duplicates. If you know there are no duplicates, you should always use `UNION ALL`, to avoid unnecessary sorting for duplicates removement. On the other hand - `UNION ALL` doesn't grant the result to be sorted as expected, even though it works due to internal implementation. If you want a "bulletproof" sorted result, you should use an `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the UNION query like `ORDER BY Coin='USDT'`.

Comment: This question is wrong the query does not run. `ORDER BY` cannot be used before `UNION`; that's not valid SQL. Downvoting since this question has no value for stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah, the question operates from a provably false premise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

```
(SELECT * FROM Wallets WHERE NOT Coin='USDT' ORDER BY Value DESC LIMIT 1) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Wallets WHERE Coin='USDT'
```

Edit: Only works in MySQL 8

Comment: Still same result, because there are no duplicates

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This solution only works in MySQL 8.0. It does not work in MySQL 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your query is the lack of parentheses.  So, this should work:

```
(SELECT w.* 
 FROM Wallets w
 WHERE Coin <> 'USDT' 
 ORDER BY Value DESC
 LIMIT 1 
) UNION
(SELECT w.* 
 FROM Wallets w
 WHERE Coin = 'USDT'
);
```

I recommend `UNION ALL`, but it doesn't matter here, because there are no duplicates -- the column `COIN` (at least) is different.

In practice, this will return the results in order.  However, MySQL does not guarantee that the results of a `UNION ALL` are in order (as far as I know), so I think you should add an additional `ORDER BY`:

```
(SELECT w.* 
 FROM Wallets w
 WHERE Coin <> 'USDT' 
 ORDER BY Value DESC
 LIMIT 1 
) UNION ALL
(SELECT w.* 
 FROM Wallets w
 WHERE Coin = 'USDT'
)
ORDER BY (Coin <> 'USDT') DESC;
```